# error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdec

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

NetWork.hpp

```
template <typename T>
class NetWork{
public:
        NetWork(){};
        //NetWork(int inp, int out);
        NetWork(std::vector<int> layer_size);
private:
    std::vector<int> layer_size;
};
```

NetWork.cpp

```
#include "../header/NetWork.hpp"
template <typename T>
NetWork<T>::NetWork(std::vector<int> layer_size){
    for (int i = 0; i < layer_size-1; i++)
    {
        this->layers.push_back(Layer<T>(layer_size[i],layer_size[i+1]));
    }
    this->layer_size=layer_size; 
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "NetWork/header/NetWork.hpp"

int main(){
    std::vector<int> layer_size;
    layer_size.push_back(4);
    layer_size.push_back(8);
    layer_size.push_back(3);

    NetWork<float> NN(layer_size);

    return 0; 
}
```

После сборки проекта выдает ошибку:

main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl NetWork::NetWork(class
std::vector<int,class std::allocator >)" (??0?$NetWork@M@@QEAA@V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z) в функции
main. [C:\Users\TopPC\Desktop\Neuron3\MyBuild\Neuron.vcxproj]
C:\Users\TopPC\Desktop\Neuron3\MyBuild\Release\Neuron.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1 [C:
\Users\TopPC\Desktop\Neuron3\MyBuild\Neuron.vcxproj]

Comment: определение шаблона должно быть в хедере...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в конец файла, реализующий шаблонный класс

```
template class ИмяКласса<(тип1 который мб иcпользован)>
template class ИмяКласса<(тип2 который мб иcпользован)>
и т.д.
```